OpenAI ChatGPT (GPT-3.5) API error 400: Experiencing "400 Bad Request" Error when Sending Large Text Data to OpenAI API
I'm facing a "400 Bad Request" issue when attempting to send large text data to the OpenAI API for processing. Here's a overview of my project:
I have a project that integrates with the OpenAI API. The functionality allows users to send data along with questions, and the system retrieves responses based on the provided data and questions. However, when sending text data exceeding approximately 20000 characters, I consistently receive a "400 Bad Request" error. Strangely, smaller text data within the range of 20000 characters works perfectly fine
// Method to send data to OpenAI API
public Result sendData() {
    ChatGptRequest chatGptRequest = new ChatGptRequest();
    List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();

    Message userMessage = new Message();
    userMessage.setRole("user");
    userMessage.setContent("What is the start and end date?");
    messages.add(userMessage);

    Message systemMessage = new Message();
    systemMessage.setRole("system");
    systemMessage.setContent(text); // 'text' contains the large text data
    messages.add(systemMessage);

    chatGptRequest.setMessages(messages);
    String response = ChatGptClient.chatGPT(chatGptRequest);
    // Handle response as needed
    return response;
}

// Method to interact with OpenAI API
public static String chatGPT(ChatGptRequest chatGptRequest) {
    String url = "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions";
    String apiKey = "my_api_key";
    String model = "gpt-3.5-turbo";

    try {
        URL openAIUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) openAIUrl.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + apiKey);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

        chatGptRequest.setModel(model);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String body = gson.toJson(chatGptRequest);

        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        writer.write(body);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
        }
        br.close();

        return response.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

Could you please suggest any solutions for this issue? Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance

You should read the API specifications, maybe you just can't send more than 20000 chars. I mean, 20KB (assuming UTF8 within ASCII range) is quite alot.

I just did a test call to gpt-3.5-turbo, which you are using. The response data, which includes the name of the model actually being used, gave it as gpt-3.5-turbo-0125.
OpenAI give us this (https://openai.com/pricing#language-models) on gpt-3.5-turbo-0125:

gpt-3.5-turbo-0125 is the flagship model of this family, supports a
16K context window and is optimized for dialog.

So you just need to use a different model. GPT-4 Turbo has a context window of 128K for example.
